# Problems sending two parameters to mvc4 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to send two parameters to my `Chapter` controller. And then have the model to do some update, and then return to the view I started from.

What I have for now is this:

---

**Move.cshtml:**

```
<div>
    <a href='/Chapter/Move?chapterId=27&parentId=26'>Move under this</a>
</div>
```

---

**ChapterController.cs:**

```
public ActionResult Move(int chapterId)
{
    if (chapterId == 0)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    var model = new Chapter { _id = chapterId };

    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult UpdateChapterPosition(int chapterId, int parentId)
{
    Chapter.updateChapterPosition(chapterId, parentId);

    return RedirectToAction("Chapter", "Move", new { chapterId = chapterId });
}
```

---

**Chapter.cs: //Model**

```
public int _id { get; set; }
public int parentId { get; set; }

public static void updateChapterPosition(int chapterId, int parentId)
{
    var con = new    SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Database"].ConnectionString);
    con.Open();

    using (var command = new SqlCommand("update Subjects set fk_subfolderTo=@parent where _id=@id", con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("id", chapterId);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("parent", parentId);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

---

It makes a reload of the view. but doesn't update the database. And no error occurs.

Comment: You're not using the `UpdateChapterPosition` action method.

Comment: You never call UpdateChapterPosition 
<a href='/Chapter/Move?chapterId=27&parentId=26'>Move under this</a>
calls Move

Comment: Ofcourse. Why didn't I see that. Feels so dumb -.-

Comment: someone add an answer so it can be marked answered/closed..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As everyone else said in the comments, you are not calling the UpdateChapterPosition action. I'd also like to add that instead of using an html anchor tag, try using `Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Move under this", "UpdateChapterPosition", "Chapter", new { chapterId = 27, parentId = 26 })
```